# WatchKit App Rejected for "Failing to Install"

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, watchkit

I built an iOS  app with a companion Apple Watch app and recently submitted it to the App Store.  This morning, it was rejected for failing to install.  Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Install the app on iPhone
2. Launch the companion app
3. Toggle the "Show App on Apple Watch" switch
4. The app attempts to install on the Apple Watch
5. Error message is displayed on Apple Watch and app in not installed.
6. Toggle switch in the companion app is set to "off"

Obviously, I don't have an Apple Watch to test this with, but it works fine in the simulator (and installs fine on the Apple Watch simulator).  Perhaps it has something to do with how I'm signing before submission? Has anyone run into this same issue?

Here is the error message reported on the Apple Watch (given to me by Apple's Review Team):

> App Verification Failed

Comment: Dunno if this might help:http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/4/2/submitting-your-watchkit-app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you ever opened the project in Xcode 6.3? If so, it likely set your deployment target to iOS 8.3, which will cause this error.

Comment: Good catch-- the iPhone app was set back to 8.2 but the WatchKit binary was still on 8.3 (buried in the plist).  Thanks!

Comment: Wow! This is hard to find. In my case the deployment target was 8.3 on the Watch App itself (not the WatchKit extension) and that setting is not exposed in the UI at all. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue, had to open the project file and then project.pbxproj and search for deployment targets within there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you opened your project in Xcode 6.3 at some point, it updates your deployment target to iOS 8.3. This however isn't reflected in the project's UI, you have to right click your project file and show contents, then open up your project.pbxroj and search for deployment target and change it to 8.2

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error.
Went to the Apple developer portal website and to the devices section.
Then I had to go through the 'device reset' procedure.

The reason being that I had entered a new developer programme year. It seems that it had refused to provision the device until I went through that reset - not that it told me!

Once I had done this, I popped into the Window->Devices (from xCode) and I would see the watch.

From that point on it worked fine.
(I checked back in the device list on the developer Portal and there it was).

Also, if it does not turn on automatically, that Window->Devices shows the UDID that you can use to manually add your device.

Hope that might be of some help :)