# Failed to verify code signature WatchKit

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, apple-watch

I'm trying to run a WatchKit app on an Apple Watch but every time this message tells me that it cannot verify the code signature :

```
companionappd[153] <Warning>: failed to install WatchKit application, error: (Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" 
UserInfo=0x15ddfba0 {Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, 
ErrorDetail=-402620391, 
ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : 
path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.kD3tCX/extracted/com.**.**.watchkitapp.app 
identifier = com.**.**.watchkitapp type = 4> : 0xe8008019 
(Application signature not valid)})
```

But I've tried to revoke my current Developer Certificate, created a new provisioning profile for the App, the WatchKit extension, and the WatchKit App. I also put the Apple Watch Device Id on this provisioning profile.

I've deleted all the provisioning profiles on my mac, reloaded it.

I've Clean the project, removed derived data.

I've restarted my mac.

I've done this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29857073/840233

and this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452435/840233

I've done everything !

Is there someone that had the same issue and found a solution?
My next step is to do a clean install of the mac, the iPhone and the Apple Watch. But I would like to find another solution ! :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've deleted all watchkit target (extension & app), and create new one, it works now...

**EDIT**

I've found that it was one of my run script (I don't know which one) that cause the issue. 
These scripts where on Apple Watch extension target. Now my scripts stay on the main app's target !